# Knockout Observable Subscription Failling to subscribe

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a ASP.NET MVC Project and I am using knockout, I have a few checkboxes and I want them to trigger and update on the server when they change. I was adivised to use subscription and put my code (Ajax call) on the subscription callback.

The problem is that the subscription is not subscribing so the code never runs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function JobViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        var baseUri = '/Api/Pedidos/';            
        self.TotalItems = ko.observable(@Model.TotalItems);
        self.AbreviaNome = ko.observable(@Model.AbreviaNome.ToString().ToLower());
        self.AbreviaFantasia = ko.observable(@Model.AbreviaFantasia.ToString().ToLower());
        self.AbreviaLogradouro = ko.observable(@Model.AbreviaLogradouro.ToString().ToLower());
        self.AbreviaComplemento = ko.observable(@Model.AbreviaComplemento.ToString().ToLower());
        self.AbreviaBairro = ko.observable(@Model.AbreviaBairro.ToString().ToLower());
        self.AbreviaCidade = ko.observable(@Model.AbreviaCidade.ToString().ToLower());
        self.AbreviaExtra = ko.observable(@Model.AbreviaExtra.ToString().ToLower());
        self.AbreviaNomeSubscriptions = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.AbreviaNome.getSubscriptionsCount();
        })

        var updatableData = {
            Id: '@Model.Id',                
            Status: '@((int)Model.Status)',                
            File: '@Model.File',                
            AbreviaNome: self.AbreviaNome,
            AbreviaFantasia: self.AbreviaFantasia,
            AbreviaLogradouro: self.AbreviaLogradouro,
            AbreviaComplemento: self.AbreviaComplemento,
            AbreviaBairro: self.AbreviaBairro,
            AbreviaCidade: self.AbreviaCidade,
            AbreviaExtra: self.AbreviaExtra                
        };            

        self.update = function () {
            alert(updatableData.AbreviaNome());
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: baseUri + '@Model.Id',
                data: ko.toJSON(self),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json"
            })
                .done(function (data) {

                    alert('Magic');
                })
                .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    alert("fail");
                });
        };

        self.AbreviaNome.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            alert(newValue);                
            self.update();
        });
    }

    function JobDetailsViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        var baseUri = '/Api/Pedidos/';
        self.Job = new JobViewModel();            
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {            
        ko.applyBindings(new JobDetailsViewModel());            
        $('input[type=file]').bootstrapFileInput('Selecione o arquivo');            
    });
</script>
```

piece of the HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default " data-bind="css: {active:Job.AbreviaNome}">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Job.AbreviaNome" name="type" id="AbreviaNome">Nome/Razão<span data-bind="text: ' (' + Job.AbreviaNomeSubscriptions() + ')'"></span><span data-bind="text: ' (' + Job.AbreviaNome() + ')'"></span></input>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" data-bind="css: {active: Job.AbreviaFantasia}">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Job.AbreviaFantasia" name="type" id="AbreviaFantasia">Apelido/ Fantasia </input>
    </label>
</div>
```

Looks like everything is correct, but when I click the checkbox, nothing happens.

EDIT:

I have not yet found a solution but it seems like bootstrap is influencing on how things happen here. The fact that the Label that defines the "color" and "activity" of the checkbox, is around it, when the checkbox is clicked it changes the state (active/not active) but does not change the value of checkbox, thus not triggering anything else.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: Nope, the is nothing on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding expression is

```
data-bind="checked: Job.AbreviaNome"
```

I guess you are using a "with" statement earlier in your HTML - or something that defines "Job"? Otherwise you should get an error but you state there is nothing in the console.

The initial value of AbreviaNome is @Model.AbreviaNome.ToString().ToLower() and this might not convert to the boolean value that the "checked" binding expects.

Comment: The value is being set correctly but the subscription never happens, if you look on the code I look at the "Job.AbreviaNomeSubscriptions()" , it always returns ZERO.

Comment: I don't use a with, Job is a "property" of the parent view (JobDetailsViewModel), and thats why I used "Job.AbreviaNome" as the bind.

Comment: @Model.AbreviaNome.ToString().ToLower() result in "true" or "false", and that is the appropriate jscript sintax, if I don't do that I get an error that states "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'True' is undefined"

Comment: I found something odd, it looks like the binding is happening only one way... so it set the correct value when the page loads, but when I make any change nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you are doing everything correctly.  In fact, when I extract the relevant parts of your code to test, it works perfectly!

[JSFiddle Test](http://goo.gl/gEdWP4)

Please check again for any console errors during load and after changing the checkbox value.